# Linq to Entities Percentages

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, percentage

Does anyone have any tips for calculating percentages in Linq to Entities?

I'm guessing that there must be a more efficient way than returning 2 results and calculating in memory. Perhaps an inventive use of let or into?

EDIT

---

Thanks Mark for your comment, here is a code snippet, but I think this will result in 2 database hits:

```
int passed = (from lpt in this.PushedLearnings.Select(pl => pl.LearningPlanTask)
where lpt.OnlineCourseScores.Any(score => score.ActualScore >= ((lpt.LearningResource.PassMarkPercentage != (decimal?)null) ?lpt.LearningResource.PassMarkPercentage : 80))
select lpt).Count();

int total = (from lpt in this.PushedLearnings.Select(pl => pl.LearningPlanTask)
select lpt).Count();

double percentage = passed * 100 / total;
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: Thanks @MarkByers I've popped on a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

If you use LINQ to Entities and write something along the lines of `select x * 100.0 / y` in your query then this expression will be converted to SQL and run in the database. It will be efficient.